# How is req.body correctly mapped to the const array of variables in here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was following along a course and can't understand how does the express correctly maps the values in the JSON of the request's body to the array of const variables.

The raw JSON in the body of the post request is:

```
{
  "status":"Systems Engineer",
  "skills":"HTML ,CSS, Python, Machine Learning"
}
```

In server.js I have initialized Middleware as:

```
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
```

At backend in profile.js file:

```
const {
      company,
      website,
      location,
      bio,
      status,
      githubusername,
      skills,
      youtube,
      twitter,
      facebook,
      linkedin,
      instagram
    } = req.body;

console.log(status);
console.log(skills);
```

Output:

"Systems Engineer"

"HTML ,CSS, Python, Machine Learning"

Comment: There is no array in your code? And if you refer to the destructuring, that has nothing to do with express. All it does is to create the `req.body` object.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I just looked up destructuring. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of Express middleware:

```
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
```

reads the body of the request from the incoming http request stream and then parses the JSON found in that request body.  The resulting properties from the parsed JSON are put into the object `req.body` for a subsequent request handler to use the data from there.  That middleware populates whatever properties it finds in the parsed JSON.

This part of your code:

```
const {
      company,
      status,
      skills,
      ...
      instagram
    } = req.body;
```

is called object destructuring in Javascript (nothing to do with Express).  It is basically equivalent to this code:

```
const company = req.body.company;
const status = req.body.status;
const skills = req.body.skills;
...
const instagram = req.body.instagram;
```

Any property with a named variable that doesn't exist in `req.body` will just end up with a corresponding variable with an `undefined` value in it.  The ones that do exist will copy the value of that property over to the named variable.

Also, there is no array in your code.  The first code block above is object destructuring syntax in Javascript.